# How to edit library package inside docker image

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I want to manually change some source code in a .py file inside `gensim` library, which is installed inside a docker image after `pip install -r requirements.txt` which has `gensim` library version specified inside.

Since I'm using `requirements.txt`, changing source code locally (or on ec2) then building won't solve the problem.

Changing docker image after I pull it won't solve the problem since it won't be easily repeatable for other computers.

My current thought is to have that edited .py file inside the same directory as `Dockerfile` and make my `application.py` import from the modified .py file and build the image. Is (this a good way or) there a better way for docker to install a customized library?

Answer (score 1):

If you 'own' the image and Dockerfile, then you can add the python file in it:

```
RUN pip install --requirement requirements.txt
ADD changed_source.py intended_location
...
```

If you don't own the image|Dockerfile, then a better practice is to derive a new image from it:

```
FROM the-other-file:tag
ADD changed_source.py intended_location
...
```

Make sense?

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply! So I should have changed_source.py inside the same directory as Dockerfile if I want to build docker image from scratch, correct? And if I add changed_source.py to the intended_location, does it automatically replace the original source code with the same file name?  Also how can I find the intended_location within docker? Is there an easy way to find the path? Also what is "the-other-file" you are referring to?

Comment: The `Dockerfile` and `changed_source.py` needn't be in the same directory (thought it's easier). They do need to be in the same context (think under the same parent directory). If you `ADD changed_sourced.py [location]`, it will create|replace the file in `[location]`. Your best bet to find the correct location, is (to hope the image includes a shell and) to shell into the current image `docker run --interactive --tty [the-original-image] /bin/bash` and `find` or look for the file. Sorry `the-other-file` would have been better named `the-original-image`.